# How to Find Image Type from New Image Created Via PHP

Tags: php, image

```
<?php

$server_root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];


$auction = $_GET['auction'];
$item = $_GET['item'];
$dir = $_GET['dir'];
$img = urldecode($_GET['img']);

$image = explode('/',$img);
//parse out the file name
$folder = '/'.$image[3].'/';

$file = $image[4];
$image = $folder.$file;
$imagePath = $server_root.$image;

//set the correct direction
if ($dir == 'ccw') {
    $degrees = 90;
} else {
    $degrees = '270';
}
$source = imagecreatefromjpeg($imagePath);

$rotate = imagerotate($source, $degrees, 0);


//delete the old file
unlink($imagePath);
$newFile = 'img_'.$item.'_'.time().'.jpg';
// $newFile = 'img_'.$item.'.jpg';

$newFileName = $server_root.$folder.$newFile;


imagejpeg($rotate, $imagePath);


imagedestroy($source);
imagedestroy($rotate);


?>
```

I'm trying to grab the image type after using the above code snippet to rotate and save that rotated image.

I tried using:

```
$typeString = null;
$typeInt = exif_imagetype($newFilename);
switch($typeInt) {
  case IMG_GIF:
    $typeString = 'image/gif';
    break;
  case IMG_JPG:
    $typeString = 'image/jpg';
    break;
  case IMG_JPEG:
    $typeString = 'image/jpeg';
    break;
  case IMG_PNG:
    $typeString = 'image/png';
    break;
  case IMG_WBMP:
    $typeString = 'image/wbmp';
    break;
  case IMG_XPM:
    $typeString = 'image/xpm';
    break;
  default:
    $typeString = 'unknown';
}
```

But that kept outputting an error. So I'm not sure what is the best solution to grab the image type based on the above code. The reason I need the image type is to use a function I created to made 3 different sized images for that image and that function requires an image type, but I can't seem to figure out how to pull the image type using the above snippet.

Comment: "But that kept outputting an error"  And what exactly is the error?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `mime_content_type()` to get the content type of a file.

**Without switch statement:**

```
$typeString = mime_content_type($newFilename);
$typeInt = exif_imagetype($newFilename);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
switch(exif_imagetype($newFilename)) {
    case IMAGETYPE_GIF:
$typeString = 'image/gif';
    case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
$typeString = 'image/jpeg';
    case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
    $typeString = 'image/png';
    break;
```

Answer (score 0):

IMG_GIF should be IMAGETYPE_GIF

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-imagetype.php#refsect1-function.exif-imagetype-constants